# Objective-C SDL Binding?

Tags: objective-c, sdl

Is there an up-to-date Objective-C binding for SDL on OSX? I've been looking but everything I've found so far is out of date/not updated by a few years.

Comment: SDL itself hasn't been updated for a few years. They probably are up to date. When SDL 2 is released that'll be another matter though, although I don't see that happening for awhile.

Comment: I didn't even know SDL2 was in the works. Is there a website or page on libsdl.org about it?

Comment: See the very last question in the FAQ on this page: http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.cgi/FAQGeneral#What.27s_up_with_SDL_2.0.3F_Can_I_help.3F